# Can you export history from Visual Studio Online to another ALM system?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I’m beginning to consider moving an on-prem TFS 2012 installation to Visual Studio Online.  So, one of the first things I started investigating was how we might export our content back out of VSO in the future if we ever decided we needed to.  The more I’m looking, the less I’m finding. It seems there was a temporary time period when VSO first went GA that Microsoft offered that capability if you asked to have it done (http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/2014-apr-3-vso.aspx).  By implication, that would seem to mean that this isn’t something that is a planned feature of VSO.

Making a commitment to house all of my source and ALM data in a repository I’d effectively be barred from leaving doesn’t sound particularly appealing.  **Am I missing something, or does Microsoft really not have export capabilities on their VSO product roadmap?**  It would seem that this would be a show-stopper for many organizations from coming onto VSO, which is a perfect application to put into the cloud IMHO.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no ALM product that provides a way to do this. So it is not a compete opportunity...

Comment: The reason the temporary downgrade ability was time limited was totally technical. The TFS team had to hold the product of VSO and TFS in feature and schema parity for the timeslot to avoid breakage. In most circumstances VSO is as much as 4 sprints (12 weeks) ahead of TFS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For code you can use Git. Even if you start with TFVC, you can use Git-TF. Clone with the --deep parameter to get the full history in a new Git repo, then push back to a new project (Git or TFVC).

For work items the TEAM tab in Microsoft Excel is a very capable export facility for work items, though you don't get links (other than parent child), or attachments.

1. In the original project, create a query that lists all your work items.
2. Open Excel, go to the TEAM tab and click 'New List', you should get the option to select your project and the query you just created.
3. In the Work Items tab select the 'Choose Columns' button and select all the columns you want to migrate.
4. If migrating to another TFS / VSO project, create that project, open another list in Excel connected to the new project.
5. Cut and paste all the work items from the original project list to the new project list (excluding the Id column).
6. Publish.

voilà.

Answer (score 3):

You're right there's no good solution for this yet.  However, if you're using Git as the source-control back-end (instead of TFVC), you can easily pull down the entire repo then push it up into any other source control server (non-VSO) with full history.

For TFVC source-control, or work items (or builds, test results, etc), things aren't so easy.

Comment: Agreed - once you get outside of basic source version control-type functionality, the data starts to diverge in semantics and usage rather quickly amongst ALMs.  We're still thinking about exactly how much of that "other" data we'd want/need to (ideally) export if push ever came to shove, but we'll give some consideration to using Git as a bit of insurance to at least make moving source code a bit easier. I guess I've described OpsHub's USP, eh?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is not black and white: with the TFS Client API you can connect to both platform and read/write as you please. It is not a trivial task, so someone has created tooling, like [Brian says](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/14/migrating-on-premises-tfs-to-vs-online.aspx). Another option is using the open source [TFS Integration Platform](http://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/): it is complex but with some help you can do it.

What you really must consider and plan is the data model: moving from an ALM Platform to another is *never* trivial and the complexity lies in the difference of the underlying model and any customization you made.

As long as you do not customize you on-prem TFS, it is very doable, with a reasonable effort to move to VSO and back. In this context customize means: custom workitems fields, types or workflows, server-side plugins; shortly anything that requires code or schema change. Note that you can still customize builds as this is properly managed.

I expect to see more solutions arriving thanks to the [new REST API](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2014/05/12/a-new-api-for-visual-studio-online.aspx), but it will take time before we see solid products.

So your original question has a positive answer (TFS on-prem -> VSO) using [OpsHub](http://www.opshub.com/main/index.php/products/vsomigrationutility), but know what you are doing and, as I write, it is practically a one way journey.